# How to update cell values while iterating through rows in an .xlsx file?

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I'm trying to read an excel file with the Pandas library, iterate through all of the rows and change some values in them. The table looks somewhat like this:
[Table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T28o9.png)
So my goal here is to change value of the login column for all rows to first name + last name, just like this:
[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeRYg.png)

In order to do this, I've tried this:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_excel('contestants.xlsx', sheet_name = 0)
df.reset_index(drop=True)
for i, r in df.iterrows():
    row = r.copy()
    login = row['First name']+row['Last name']
    df.loc[i, 'Login'] = login
    print(df['Login'][i])
```

But neither df.loc nor df.at worked at all. The print function gives the expected output, but the .xlsx file itself doesn't change. How can I fix this?

Comment: You have to write the resulting `DataFrame` back to the file with `to_excel`.  Btw no need to loop at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fyi, as Ben suggested, it's faster not to loop:

```py
df = pandas.read_excel('contestants.xlsx', sheet_name = 0)
df['Login'] = df['First name']+df['Last name']
```

Also, check the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

> Note that creating an ExcelWriter object with a file name that already
> exists will result in the contents of the existing file being erased.

meaning that if there are more sheets in your excel file you need to import them all, update the first one, and store them all.

See https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_multiple.html for a working example